# Multiple level of abstract concrete base in SQLAlchemy inheritance hierarchy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, polymorphism

I'd like to be able to query entities(tables) in an inheritance hierarchy at multiple levels.

That is, if I have

`Base---------------------------------|
  |                                                  |
Child1----------|                       |
  |                   |                        |
Child2         Child3              Child4`

where Base and Child1 are abstract(i.e. are not mapped to a table);
I'd like to query entities from tables `Child2`, `Child3` and `Child4` through `Base`, and `Child2` and `Child3` through `Child1`.

The problem is, I don't think it's possible to have multiple `AbstractConcreteBase` classes in a hierarchy. So I have to choose to be able to make polymorphic queries on either `Base` or `Child1`.

Is there a way to do this? An alternative pattern, maybe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is [joined-table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance).

Each level of abstraction is mapped to an actual table containing only the columns specific to that level. SQLAlchemy does the job of generating the right `JOIN`s to get data from each table.